# ERROR:"System can not find the path specified"

Tags: delphi, iis, ole

I am getting error as `System can not find the path specified`.

The error is showing in the following code function:

```
function VirtualDirectoryExists(VirtualDirectoryName : String) : Boolean;
var
  BindContext: IBindCtx;
  Eaten: longint;
  Moniker: IMoniker;
  ObjectDispatch: IDispatch;
  VariantObject: Variant;
  WebVirtualDir: Variant;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, BindContext));
 try
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindContext, 'IIS://localhost/W3SVC', Eaten, Moniker));
 except
  on E : Exception do
  begin
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;
 end;
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindContext, nil, IDispatch, ObjectDispatch));
  VariantObject := ObjectDispatch;
 try
  // below statement throws exception
   WebVirtualDir := VariantObject.GetObject('IisWebVirtualDir', '1/Root/' + VirtualDirectoryName); 
  Result := True;
 except
  Result := False;
 end;
end;
```

The parameter passed to this procedure is as follows:

`VirtualDirectoryName = 'MYWebSite'`

I am not able to trace it out.

The statement `WebVirtualDir := VariantObject.GetObject('IisWebVirtualDir', '1/Root/' + VirtualDirectoryName);` throws exception.

And I am using `IIS 7.5` version win `windows 7`.

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line of code raises the error?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please check I did the changes.

Comment: We still don't know which line of code fails, and it would be an awful lot of work for us to set up and replicate the same environment as you have (which we know nothing about). You need to provide more information. We don't even know which version of IIS you're using.

Comment: @JerryDodge Please check I did the changes and highlight the exception causing statement, let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't a problem in your Delphi code, but a problem with how this site is set up. Does this virtual directory actually exist? Because based on how this code is supposed to work, this exception is supposed to happen - but you're only going to see it in debug mode. In runtime, you wouldn't see this exception, but it will return false instead (assuming it doesn't exist).

Comment: @JerryDodge thanks jerry as per your suggestion I have checked the site and yes it does not have a virtual directory.
I have one more query that what is a significance of folder icon and globe icon in the IIS.
Because I need to delete the web virtual directory but not able to understand the significance of the `folder` and `globe in hand` icon of iis